# UIButton within UIView loaded from xib not call the selector at all when click

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have struggling this issue for many days and hope someone can help me on this.

I created an `UIView` called "mFavorite" which inherits from `NSObject`. The reason for this is the view is going to be loaded from nib and set up when it initialized from used `ViewController`.

I can see it being initiated right but when I click it just never called the selector ***favoriteTapped***.

The class of *mFavorite* is as bellow:

```
import UIKit
let favoriteDataModel = FavoriteDataModel()
let favoriteFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 31, height: 29)

protocol mFavoriteDelegate: class{
  func mFavoriteFavoriteIconDidPressed()
}

class mFavorite: NSObject{
  var frame: CGRect
  var view:UIView!
  var favoriteName: String
  var sourceViewController: ViewControllerBase?
  weak var delegate: mFavoriteDelegate?
  var isFavorite: Bool = false{
    didSet{
      updateImage()
      updateFavoriteToDataModel()
    }
  }

  init(sourceViewController: ViewControllerBase, favoriteName: String, frame: CGRect){
    self.sourceViewController = sourceViewController
    self.favoriteName = favoriteName
    self.frame = frame
    self.isFavorite = favoriteDataModel.isFavoriteExist(favoriteName)
    super.init()
    setup()
  }

  convenience init(sourceViewController: ViewControllerBase, favoriteName: String){
    self.init(sourceViewController: sourceViewController, favoriteName: favoriteName, frame: favoriteFrame)
  }

  func setup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = frame

    let btnfavorite = view.viewWithTag(ViewTags.btnFavorite) as! UIButton
    btnfavorite.addTarget(self, action: "favoriteTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
    //btnfavorite.userInteractionEnabled = true

    sourceViewController?.view.addSubview(view)
    let widthConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: view.frame.size.width)
    let heightConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: view.frame.size.height)
    let topConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: sourceViewController?.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: view.frame.origin.y)
    let trailConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .Trailing , relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: sourceViewController?.view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: screenWidth - 20)

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([widthConstraints, heightConstraints, topConstraints, trailConstraints])

  }

  func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    //let bundle = NSBundle(forClass:self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "mFavorite", bundle: nil)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
  }

  func updateImage(){
    let btnfavorite = view.subviews[0] as! UIButton
    let img = isFavorite ? UIImage(named: "star-yellow") : UIImage(named: "star-grey")
    btnfavorite.setBackgroundImage(img, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  }

  func updateFavoriteToDataModel(){
    if isFavorite{
      favoriteDataModel.addToFavorite(favoriteName)
    }else{
      favoriteDataModel.removeFromFavorite(favoriteName)
    }
  }
  func favoriteTapped(sender: UIButton){
    isFavorite = !isFavorite
    delegate!.mFavoriteFavoriteIconDidPressed()
  }
}
```

With this *mFavorite*, I then create it in other `UIViewController` by the following code:

```
let favoriteIcon = mFavorite(sourceViewController: self, favoriteName: FavoriteNames.Parking, frame: CGRect(x: 265, y: 118, width: favoriteFrame.width, height: favoriteFrame.height))
favoriteIcon.delegate = self
```

I here also attached the nib that i created (it's really simple just a button)

[image]

The background has changed to indicate that the button is created inside the container bounds.

[image]

Comment: Change the background color of the UIView and button to see if the button draws within the container view bounds, otherwise the UIView will not entertain the touches for button.

Comment: @ NeverHopeless, i had changed it and confirm that the button draws within the container view bounds.

Comment: I am not sure why, but in my project, I tried adding a button, and it wouldn't call the selector until I added `@objc` to the function signature. Not sure if this will help, or why it worked for me.

Comment: @ hannad, yes, i did try it as well. but still not work. The funny thing is that i use the same structure for other views (like customized Navigation Bar..) and it's work. However, i really have no idea why this one is not work at all......!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer that the code bellow wrote in the *viewDidLoad* got the problem. The local variable created is no longer hold after draw on the view.

```
let favoriteIcon = mFavorite(sourceViewController: self, favoriteName: FavoriteNames.Parking, frame: CGRect(x: 265, y: 118, width: favoriteFrame.width, height: favoriteFrame.height))
```

The solution i made is the following:

1. In my ViewControllerBase (inherits from UIViewController), i hold a

   ```
   var favorite: mFavorite?
   ```
2. In the derivative class (inherits from ViewControllerBase), i initialize it with the following:

   ```
   favoriteIcon = mFavorite(sourceViewController: self, favoriteName: FavoriteNames.Parking, frame: CGRect(x: 265, y: 118, width: favoriteFrame.width, height: favoriteFrame.height))
   ```

The question might sounds a little bit stupid but hope it does give an hint for someone that meeting similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because your button is inside a view hierarchy that's being drawn past its bounds, then the touch is only captured inside views' bounds. If you add the clip mask to the view hierarchy and your button doesn't appear, there's something wrong in the frames of the parent views, probably in the sourceViewController's view.

Try to add the following code at the end of your `setup` function:

```
// recursively clip all the ancestor views to their bounds
var aView = view
while aView != nil {
    aView.clipsToBounds = true
    aView = aView.superview
}
```